# How to disable UTF character (punctuation) escaping when creating XML using default to_xml with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, utf-8, xml-serialization

Given a rails models column that contains
"Something & Something Else" when outputting to_xml
Rails will escape the Ampersand like so:

```
<MyElement>Something &amp; Something Else</MyElement>
```

Our client software is all UTF aware and it would be better if we can just leave the column content raw in our XML output.

There was an old solution that worked by setting $KCODE="UTF8" in an environment file, but this trick no longer works, and was always an All or Nothing solution.

Any recommendations on how to disable this? on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter if the client software is UTF-8-aware. An ampersand [cannot be used unescaped](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) in XML. If the software is supposed to also be XML-aware, then any content that includes ampersands is not allowed to be kept "raw".

Comment: There is the CDATA option, but I don't really want to wrap every XML text object I am putting in my XML output with CDATA.  So I'm considering living with it.  And oh, yeah, DoH! Of course, It's not allowed.

Comment: Straight out of the XML spec.

"The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section"

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Unicode (or "UTF"). Ampersands in XML must be escaped, otherwise it isn't XML, and no XML software will accept it. If you're saying you want the escaping disabled, then you're saying you don't want the output to be XML.